# how to get indexes of the first three maximum values in the array list

Tags: java

tvalue is my array list,i want to retrive index of the frist three maximum values in the arraylist,by using the below code i am getting wrong values could any help me out

```
int index = Colletions.max(tvalue);
 if ((index + 1) > 10) {
     data = data + "Node" + (index + 1);
 } else if ((index + 1) <= 10) {
     data = data + "Node-" + (index + 1) + " + ";
     System.out.println((index + 1));
 }
 }
 Collections.sort(tvalue);
 int in = tvalue.indexOf(tvalue.get(tvalue.size() - 2));
 System.out.println(tvalue.get(tvalue.size() - 2)); {
     if (( in +1) > 10) {
         data = data + "Node-" + (( in +1) - 10) + " + ";
         System.out.println(( in +1) - 10);
     } else if (( in +1) <= 10) {
         data = data + "Node-" + ( in +1) + " + ";
         System.out.println(( in +1));
     }
 }

 int id = tvalue.indexOf(tvalue.get(tvalue.size() - 3));
 System.out.println(tvalue.get(tvalue.size() - 3)); {
     if ((id + 1) > 10) {
         data = data + "Node-" + ((id + 1) - 10) + " + ";
         System.out.println((id + 1) - 10);
     } else if ((id + 1) <= 10) {
         data = data + "Node-" + (id + 1) + " + ";
         System.out.println((id + 1));
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using streams in one line, please find below example.

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(1000, 2000).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
list.stream().sorted((v1,v2)->v2.compareTo(v1)).limit(3).map(v->list.indexOf(v)).forEach(i->System.out.println(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

first sort your collection into descending order and store it into one temparary variable.. now pick three value from the top (these are your three maximum value). now compare this value with your original arraylist.. suppose value are 1 to 10, so your three max values are 10,9, and 8. suppose i m storing these value in temp array.

```
int k=0;
for(int i=0; i<collectinolist.count; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<temp.count; j++)
    {
          if(collection[i]==temp[j])
          {
            maxthreevalue[k]=i;
            k++;
          }
    }
}
```

now your maxthreevalue variable contains three index where your three max values are stored.!
Thanks.

Comment: Don't Copy the Code, just follow the Procedure. First Reverse the Array and save it into another Array, Extract first three value these are your max three values, now compare these value with your original Array, it may give you Indexes. Hope now you Understand.!

Answer (score 0):

First copy your arrayList to another arrayList and then sort it. The sorted array will be used to know the larger elements, and once you know which element is biggest you can use the indexOf() method in the **unsorted arrayList** to get the index. If you sort it without getting a copy first, you just lost the information you are looking for.

```
List sortedValue = new ArrayList<>(tvalue); //gets a copy
Collections.sort(sortedValue);              //sorts the copy
for (int i=1; i<4; i++) {                   //prints the the biggest three
    System.out.println(tvalue.indexOf(tvalue.get(sortedValue.size() - i)));
}
```